# Can Jenkins be installed with the command line (not the GUI)?

Tags: jenkins

I am writing a script to set up Jenkins instances, but I could not find a non-GUI way to perform the "initial installation", which comprises the "unlocking" with the initial admin password and selecting plugins (see image).

[image: Jenkins installation wizard GUI]

My question is: is there a way to do this with the command line, something like:

```
# this is an example, it does not work
./var/jenkins_home/scripts/install-jenkins.sh standard
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the system property `jenkins.install.runSetupWizard` to `false` to skip both install and upgrade wizards -- this will not enable security options either:

```
java -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false -jar jenkins.war
```

For more information:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!